# Create AWS Connect Contact flow using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to create a contact flow in my connect instance and keep getting the following issue when trying to use the AWS CLI.

> An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the CreateContactFlow operation: Invalid request

```
aws connect create-contact-flow --instance-id b835bc8c-7c26-4f26-a471-16b806ccf1a2 --name jenkinsTest --type CONTACT_FLOW --content "{\"Version\":\"2019-10-30\",\"StartAction\":\"1a34ecf3-77ff-46a7-b210-38a1a980127b\",\"Metadata\":{\"entryPointPosition\":{\"x\":75,\"y\":20},\"snapToGrid\":false,\"ActionMetadata\":{\"1a34ecf3-77ff-46a7-b210-38a1a980127b\":{\"position\":{\"x\":258,\"y\":66},\"audio\":[{\"type\":\"Text\",\"tts\":\"<speak>You are on hold <break time=\\\"10s\\\"/></speak>\",\"$$hashKey\":\"01J\",\"ttsType\":\"ssml\"}],\"timeoutUnit\":{\"display\":\"Minutes\",\"value\":\"min\"}}}},\"Actions\":[{\"Identifier\":\"1a34ecf3-77ff-46a7-b210-38a1a980127b\",\"Parameters\":{\"Messages\":[{\"SSML\":\"<speak>You are on hold <break time=\\\"10s\\\"/></speak>\"}]},\"Transitions\":{\"Errors\":[],\"Conditions\":[]},\"Type\":\"MessageParticipantIteratively\"}]}"
```

I am using the above CLI command. Can Any one help me to figure out this error?
[MigrateContactFlows API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/migrate-contact-flows.html)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to solve this? You can also simplify the cli command --content file://path/jsonfile/file.json

Comment: you need to replace the arn values of lambda lex and other,this link will be helpful  [link](https://github.com/ramprasadsv?tab=repositories)